# Why does $tr({A^*}A) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\sigma _i}^2} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ have eigenvalues ${\lambda _1}.....{\lambda _n}$ and singular values ${\sigma _1}.....{\sigma _n}$. Why does $tr({A^*}A) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\sigma _i}^2} $?

Answer (score 3):

The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. (This is because the trace is invariant for similar matrices and you can diagonalize each symmetric matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal).

The squared singular values $\sigma_i^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$.

EDIT: important is to note that you have to count the eigenvalues and singular values according to their multiplicities - otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: Notice that your last claim is not correct...

Comment: Which claim you mean? Singular values defined as are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, not of $A A^*$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularValue.html

Comment: They are the *square roots* of those eigevalues (as that same page makes clear)

Comment: @AndreasH. The order is not important, since $A A^*$ and $A^* A$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: ahh, I also noticed it and corrected it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- The singular values are, by definition, the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^*$, so the sum of their squares is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $AA^*$.
- The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.